# Games people play

Tags: meaning

Eric Berne wrote his famous book **”Games People Play.**”

Has this title other meaning than **People play games**?

Comment: It is a psychology book about *games played by people*, where the games are the transactional strategies and tactics used in social interactions.

Comment: @Henry, thanks for your comment, but what is the **difference** between those 2 phrases (out of context that the one of it is the title of a book)?

Comment: Book titles are probably more often ***noun phrases*** (such as this one) rather than actual sentences. But I can't really see the point of this question. Obviously noun phrases and sentences can't "mean" the same thing, but unless it's something like ***Eats shoots and leaves***, who cares about the syntax of a book title?

Comment: You should understand the title as "[A book about the] games [which] people play".

Comment: @FumbleFingers, does it mean that **Games People Play** is not a complete sentence, while **People play games** is?

Comment: Obviously that's what I mean. Is it that you don't know what a ***noun** [phrase]* is? That should be fairly easy for you to look up. If you don't understand exactly what a *sentence* is, that could be a bit more complicated. But a noun is *not* a sentence according to most definitions, so once you understand that *Games People Play = **The** games **that** people play* is a noun phrase, you can be sure it's not a sentence.

Comment: @FumbleFingers, thank you very much, now I understand. Please may you put it as an answer to enable me to accept and upvoting it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Book titles (such as the title of this question) are probably more often [***noun phrases***](https://www.twinkl.co.uk/teaching-wiki/noun-phrase) rather than actual [***sentences***](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/sentence). And obviously noun phrases and sentences can't "mean" the same thing, because by almost all definitions, a noun phrase can be *part* of a sentence, but it can't be considered a sentence on its own, with no "active" verb.

We don't normally pay much attention to conventional syntax in the context of things like book / movie / song titles, newspaper headlines, etc. (the people who *write* those titles don't take much notice of grammatical rules either! :)

As commented, *Games People Play* is effectively a reduced version of the noun phrase *[the] games [which/that] people play*, where *which people play* adjectivally modifies the "head" noun ***games***.

That noun phrase is NOT the same as the actual sentence *People play games*, which is an assertion about what people do.

---

TL;DR:

Nouns and noun phrases (such as the title of this question) are not "sentences" by most people's definition.